# How do I input variables into sql?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to input variables into a SQL table these variables are set above in the code.
This is what's causing me the issue:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO weather VALUES (temp, hum, pres)")
```

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: im using sqlite3

Comment: Can you provide the code where you set your variables?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the documentation over at [sqlite documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

```
# Do this instead
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
print c.fetchone()

# Larger example that inserts many records at a time
purchases = [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
             ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
             ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
            ]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)
```

---

**NEVER DO THIS!
IT WILL MAKE YOUR CODE VUNERABLE TO SQL INJECTION ATTACKS**

```
symbol = 'RHAT'
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)
```

or

```
c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '{symbol}'")
```

**NEVER DO THIS!
IT WILL MAKE YOUR CODE VUNERABLE TO SQL INJECTION ATTACKS**

---

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO weather VALUES (?, ?, ?)", temp, hum, pres)
```